# Overlapping vector heads

Tags: graphics, tikz-arrows, vector

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, chngcntr, textgreek, tikz, siunitx}

\begin{document}

\section{Kinematics}

\Problem A ship moves along the equator to the east with velocity $v_0 = 30$ km/hour. The southeastern wind blows at an angle $\phi = 60^{\circ}$ to the equator with velocity $v = 15$ km/hour. Find the wind velocity $v'$ relative to the ship and the angle $\phi'$ between the equator and the wind direction in the reference frame fixed to the ship.

\TheSolution 
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->](0,0) -- (-1,1) ;
    \draw[->](-0.2,1) -- (-1,1) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Now after compiling this,

[image: diagram]

Now as you see in the picture those vectors heads turn into a mess, so is there solution to beautify it or atleast make it readable.

Comment: One possibility would be to let the arrow heads be drawn in the middle of the line instead of the end. For this, see https://latexdraw.com/how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-a-line-in-tikz/

Comment: oh nice idea I'll try to make it

Comment: How about `\draw[->, shorten >=3pt] ...;`?

Comment: You could change the arrowhead, e.g., `\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]`